# how to show that Re(cosz/e^z) is harmonic over the whole complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that a function is said to be harmonic is it is already analytic and 
satisfies Laplace equations but how i can get to divide this function in to two parts to apply CR equations to prove it is entire hence analytic everywhere hence harmonic everywhere?

Comment: $\cos(z)$ and $1/\exp(z) = \exp(-z)$ are entire.  The product of two entire functions is entire.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Israel said:

1. The product of entire functions $\cos z$ and $\exp(-z)$ is entire (i.e., holomorphic in $\mathbb C$).
2. The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic: this is a well-known fact that is easy to derive from the Cauchy-Riemann equations.